# Exact number of steps in a recursion

Tags: asymptotics, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I am studying algorithms and I came across this problem:

$t(1) = 1$ and $t(n) = 4t(n/2) + n^2$
Calculate the exact value of $t(n)$ for all $n=2^l, l \in N $

Initially I thought this would be a master theorem problem, but how would I go on to find the exact value of a recursion equation?

Comment: Have you looked at the first few terms? Can you find a pattern? Note that the fact that it's asking you to look at only powers of 2 makes all the calculations quite a bit simpler...

Comment: If I find a pattern can I use induction to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can rewrite the recurrence:
$$
T(2^\ell) = 4T(2^{\ell-1})+ 4^\ell,\ \ T(2^0)=1.
$$

Computing the first few values, we have:
\begin{align}
T(2^0) &= T(1) = 1\\
T(2^1) &= 4T(2^0) + 4^1 = 4\cdot1 + 4 = 8\\
T(2^2) &= 4T(2^1) + 4^2 = 4\cdot 8 + 16 =  48\\
T(2^3) &= 4(2^2) + 4^3 = 4\cdot 48 + 64 = 256.
\end{align}

This suggests the pattern $T(2^\ell) = 4^\ell(1+\ell)$. Indeed, $T(2^0) = 4^0(1+0) = 1$, and if $T(2^\ell) = 4^\ell(1+\ell)$ for some $\ell\geqslant 0$ then
$$
T(2^{\ell+1}) = 4T(2^{\ell}) + 4^\ell = 4^\ell(2+\ell),
$$
so by induction this expression holds for all nonnegative integers $\ell$.